# Cannot get Data from the intent - Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am a beginner and I am trying to make an Intent Calculator, means I am add the inputs through Intent extras and starting a new activity for calculating the input. Finally I am trying to receive the result using onActivityResult(). The problem is i have set the result to text view, the text view detects it as a double value(displaying 0.0 from default text). I cant understand where the problem is as there are no errors in Logcat even. Below is my code. When I press the button it just displays 0.0. No matter how many times i click. Also I am practicing Intents so just tried the basic one. Kindly help me.

```
public class InputActivity extends Activity {


final int CALCULATION_COMPLETE = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);

    final EditText num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1_edit);
    final EditText num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2_edit);

    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resultButton);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String  firstNum =  num1.getText().toString();
        String secondNum = num2.getText().toString();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(InputActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("first", firstNum);
        resultIntent.putExtra("second", secondNum);
        startActivityForResult(resultIntent, CALCULATION_COMPLETE);
        }
    });     
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent d){
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, d);
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    if(reqCode == CALCULATION_COMPLETE && resCode == RESULT_OK){

        Intent resultData = getIntent();
        Double addResult = resultData.getDoubleExtra("result", 0);

        String resultStr = addResult.toString();

        result.setText(resultStr);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent calcIntent = getIntent();
    String firstStr = calcIntent.getStringExtra("first");
    String secondStr = calcIntent.getStringExtra("second");

    Double firstNum = Double.parseDouble(firstStr);
    Double secondNum = Double.parseDouble(secondStr);

    Double addResult = firstNum + secondNum;

    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra("result", addResult);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, result );
    finish();       
}
```

}

Comment: First comment: have you used the Eclipse debugger to step through your code to make sure that it behaves the way you expect? Second comment: It seems strange to call `finish()` from `onCreate()`. If this is an example that you are using to learn how Intents work, I suggest adding a button to your second Activity which, when clicked, calls `setResult()` and `finish()`.

Comment: Thank you But I have tried as CodeMagic said. Actually I understood that we should call finsih() during onDestry(). Just wanted to do it quick. If I am wrong Kindly make me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d` is your `Intent` variable in `onActivityResult()` so try changing

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent d){
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, d);
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    if(reqCode == CALCULATION_COMPLETE && resCode == RESULT_OK){

        Intent resultData = getIntent();

        Intent calcIntent = getIntent();
```

to

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent d){
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, d);
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    if(reqCode == CALCULATION_COMPLETE && resCode == RESULT_OK){

        Intent resultData = d;  //This line here
```

If this doesn't fix your problem then please be a little more clear on what is/isn't happening.

Also, I agree with Monad's comment. While it shouldn't be causing a problem it does seem a little strange to do all of this on `onCreate()` and you may be a little better off with a `Button` or some user input. Otherwise, there really is no need for a separate `Activity` but you could use a function to do the calculation in the first `Activity`.

**Edit**

[From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29)

> Return the intent that started this activity.

so this won't return the `Intent` passed from the second `Activity` in `setResult()`. It will return an `Intent` that started this `Activity` that you would use in `onCreate()` possibly. In this situation, the `Activity` isn't being started but brought back to the top of the stack when the second `Activity` is finished and `setResult()` is called.

Comment: Thank you for your help Code Magic. Actually it worked as you said. I can able to understand that d is an intent argument. But whats the problem with getIntent() ? Does it not return the Intent as well? Eclipse doesn't show any error as well.

Comment: I have edited with a better explanation. You are welcome and you can thank me by clicking the check mark next to the answer so others can find it easier ;)

Comment: Yes I understood. But I just wanted to make it simple. I may even use a thread(if its a big calculation), or in the same activity. But I just wanted to send and retrieve data. I dont wanted to disturb My second activity.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you are getting it then :)

Comment: Thank you for you explanation I clearly understood now. It just called the Intent that started my first activity and not the one from set result.