# Android onCreate() and onResume() query

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, oncreate, onresume

I have 3 classes **A**, **B** and **C**.

I pass some objects from **A** to **B**. In **B**, in the `onCreate()`, I pull these out from the intent, and keep them as class variables. Now activity **B** allows the user to edit those objects. This happens through `startActivityForResult()` by passing the objects from **B** to **C**.

Now when the user is done with editing, **C** passes a result int back to **B** along with the modified objects, and finishes. Now when I am back to **B**, in `onActivityResult()`, I pull these objects out, and update the respective class variables. But the `onCreate()` is called again, and the class reverts back to the objects that **A** gave to **B** rather than keeping the ones that **C** gave to **B**.

Now if make it so that `onCreate()` of **B** makes a trip to the database everytime, and obviously it works fine. But it seems wasteful.

So, how do I handle this scenario? If the `onCreate()` is anyhow going to be called, it seems like the `onResume()`, `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` are useless, and I might as well put all the code in `onCreate()`.

Please advice!

Here is the code that takes the user from **B** to **C**

```
    public void goToC(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
        intent.putExtra("STUFF", stuff);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}
```

Here is the code in **C** that passes data back to **B**

```
long rowsUpdated = myModel.updateStuff(this, stuff);

if (rowsUpdated == 1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    // put the data in the intent
    intent.putExtra("STUFF", stuff);
    // set the flags to reuse B
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    // set result code to notify the ItemEntriesActivity
    setResult(1, intent);
    // finish the current activity i.e. C
    finish();
}
```

Here is the code in **B** that receives the above data

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (intent != null) {
            switch (resultCode) {
            case 1:
                // Update the class variable, so that onResume() gets the updated value
                stuff = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("STUFF");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

As I said, this code works correctly, but since `B.onCreate()` gets executed after this, activity B ends up using the old values again.

**Update**: I tried to use the `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)` when going back from **C** to **B**. This still does not work. Nowhere in B am I calling `finish()`. Any suggestion is appreciated!!!

**Update 2**: When I put a debug point in the `onStop()` in **B**, it is getting called as soon as I switch to **C**. No wonder the `onCreate()` in B will be called. Now my questions is why is the `onStop()` getting called. The only 'unnatural' thing I am doing in C is showing TextEdits without a keyboard using `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`. So I tried adding `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"` to the activity in the Manifest, with no difference. Again, any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `onCreate` is called when an activity must be (re-)created and you can't stop that from happening. The original intent is useful and so you get 2 different intents which you have to manage in a way that you don't overwrite it.

Comment: write the modified variables to the intent (or save them some other way). Then check for modified values, and load them in-lieu of default values in your OnCreate.

Comment: When I do a `getIntent()` in **B** I am always getting the one I sent from A. This is because I call `finish()` and not `startActivity()` in **C**. So then I should just go ahead and delete `onResume()`, `onActivityResult()`, etc??

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599674/cannot-get-data-from-the-intent-android/18599714#18599714) I think you are trying to access the wrong `Intent` data.

Comment: I am getting the correct intent in `onActivityResult()`, and the correct one in `onCreate()`.. so that is not the issue. What my question is, that should I just call `startActivity(A.class)` from **C** instead of finishing **C**, since onCreate is going to be called no matter what; or is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused on what your problem is but `onCreate()` shouldn't be called unless you are finishing that `Activity`. There is no guarantee that it won't be destroyed but if you aren't doing it yourself then it shouldn't get recreated unless you are telling it to.

Comment: That is where I am confused :) I am never finishing B, so I was thinking that the `onCreate()` won't be called, but apparently, it is always called, no matter what.

Comment: Can you post the code of the `Intent` you use to send back to `B`? And make sure you don't have `noHistory="true"` in your `manifest` and you don't have "don't keep activities" checked in your device settings.

Comment: I added the code from C that sends data to B, and code B that receives this data. I don't have those settings enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `Intent` to go to be with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
```

this constructor will create another instance of `B` which will indeed call `onCreate()`. You should be using an empty constructor

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// set result code to notify the ItemEntriesActivity
setResult(1, intent);
// finish the current activity i.e. C
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this modification did not change the outcome. This makes sense though. I need to read more on Intents I guess. Upon debugging, the onCreate() is still being hit. Any more ideas?

Comment: Hmmm...not at this time. This should have fixed it. You are not calling `finish()` in `B`, right? I've come across questions like this before and the `Intent` constructor is normally the culprit.

Comment: Nopes, I have posted the code that takes the user from B to C. It pretty much just calls `startActivityForResult()` with a new Intent. Thanks for your time though! I appreciate it!

Comment: I'm not sure right now then. I need to get to sleep soon but if I think of something by morning and it isn't solved, then I will let you know.