# Can not getIntExtra() at onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, onresume, onactivityresult

I got a problem with sending and receiving int types from one activity to another via Intent;

I'm sending it with onActivityResult() function which is placed at the receiving activity.

*The code:*

***The Sending Activity:***

```
Intent ba=new Intent();
        
MyPoints = fgv.getPoints();

int MP=(int)MyPoints;
Log.i("Problem","MyPoints MP = "+MP);

ba.putExtra("FocusScore",MP);
Log.i("Problem","MyPoints = "+MP);

setResult(RESULT_OK,ba);
finish();
```

The Receiving Activity:

//At the onClick in order to move the the other class

> Intent goFocus =new Intent(Games.this,FocusGame.class);
>
> startActivityForResult(goFocus,1);

//At the onActivityResult function

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {   
            
          switch (requestCode) {
            
             case 1: {
             //Coming back from Focus-Game
             //Problem:!!
                
              int sss= getIntent().getIntExtra("FocusScore", -1); 
              Log.i("Problem","sss = "+sss);
            
                 }
             break;
            
             default :
             break;
            
            }
```

}

The result of the code is given a log where sss=-1. Which means that

> getIntent().getIntExtra();

is always null.

And the Log of the MP is working fine.

### -

Hope you could help me over here.

-
Thanks in advance,
Yaniv.

Comment: What does this Log `Log.i("Problem","MyPoints MP = "+MP);`?

Comment: It show a message at the LogCat, with the tag "Problem".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get Data from the intent - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599674/cannot-get-data-from-the-intent-android)

Comment: @YanivGK the value of MP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the value of `data` not `getIntent()`

```
if (data != null) {
    //int sss= getIntent().getIntExtra("FocusScore", -1); 
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    int sss =  extras.getInt("FocusScore");
}
```

or just

```
if (data != null) {
    //int sss= getIntent().getIntExtra("FocusScore", -1);     
    int sss= data.getIntExtra("FocusScore", -1); 
}
```

More info: **[Cannot get Data from the intent - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599674/cannot-get-data-from-the-intent-android)**

Comment: Yeah.. I forgot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `getIntent()` istead of `data`

```
int sss= getIntent().getIntExtra("FocusScore", -1);
```

should be

```
int sss= data.getIntExtra("FocusScore", -1);
```

Remember that `getIntent()` returns the intent that was used to create the calling Activity, not the intent that YOU used to launch the second activity.

Comment: @YanivGK I see you accepted other's answer. My question is did you really use `Bundle extras = data.getExtras();`?? Because it shouldn't work, since you didn't pass a `bundle` as Extra.

Comment: I though the same as you. However the other code actually worked.

Comment: You don't have to pass a `Bundle` to initialize a `Bundle` from the `Intent extras`. It makes it easier to pass around to different `Activities` but that way works.