# Update a different xml layout based on a button clicked - android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

Is it possible to update what the layout is in another xml activity if you click a button.

I am building an application which has a chapter contents page (called MainActivity in the code below) which has a button that will take you to a new page containing the topics on that chapter. Currently if I click one of the chapters on the chapter contents page it will navigate to a new xml file which shows the topics contents for that selected chapter and I want to avoid this and cut down on my xml files by having dynamically changing layouts.

What I want to know how to achieve a dynamically updating layout on my tutorialpage.xml depending on what chapter button was clicked on the MainActivity page.

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="chapter1"
        android:id="@+id/chapter1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:onClick="tutorial1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="chapter2"
        android:id="@+id/chapter2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chapter1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="tutorial2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Output a string to the Log Cat
    Log.v("Message", "Output from here");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void tutorial1(View view) {

    final Button chapter1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chapter1);
    chapter1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RelativeLayout tutorial1layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tutview);
            tutorial1layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    Intent intentStart = new Intent(this, tutorialpage.class);
    startActivity(intentStart);
}


public void tutorial2(View view) {
    Intent intentStart = new Intent(this, tutorialpage.class);
    startActivity(intentStart);

    final Button chapter2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chapter2);

    chapter2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout tutorial2layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tutview2);
            tutorial2layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_tutorialpage.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="p12225720.channa.g.myapplication.tutorialpage"
    android:id="@+id/tutview"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Topic 1"
        android:id="@+id/Topic1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Topic1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="186dp"
        android:onClick="chap"/>




<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/tutview2"
    android:visibility="invisible">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Topic 6"
    android:id="@+id/Topic6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="186dp"
        android:onClick="chap"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally tutorialpage.java

public class tutorialpage extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorialpage);
}



public void chap (View view){
    Intent intentStart = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intentStart);
}
```

}

Comment: I find it hard to understand your problem. Sounds to me like you have three activities - `ChaptersActivity`, `TopicsActivity` and `TopicInfoActivity`. There isn't really a problem if you navigate through these 3 activities.  Are you saying that you want to do everything in one activity?

Comment: well each chapter currently will go to a new topic page, meaning there will be 8 topic pages, what I want is one topic page that will show the topics relating to whichever chapter you have picked. The same thing applies to each topicinfoactivity, there are 60 topics and I dont want to have to make 60+ different topicinfoactivity pages but one that will update the information shown based on what topic you click. Im assuming that it will work based on the ID of each topic button but Im not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Then having the three activities that I mentioned earlier, will do the job. Basically, what you have to do is: 1) You need to populate your `ChaptersActivity` with all the chapters you have. 2) When the user clicks on any chapter, you will open the `TopicsActivity` where you show the topics for this chapter. 3) When the user clicks on a topic, you open the `TopicInfoActivity` with the information for that topic. I suggest you to start with the beginner Android tutorials.

Comment: What I mean to ask is if there is a way to dynamically alter the layout of the next page depending on what was clicked previously. What I hope to achieve is to not have a new xml for every single new layout, however I can't find anything on how to do that, I've tried onclicklisteners and am looking at nested layouts but am not finding anything that is worthwhile at the moment.

Comment: I've added my code and updated the question if it helps to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. You can control the visibility of layout children as per need. Utilize this to create a master layout file each for chapters, topics and quiz. To achieve this, use multiple nested layouts all with `id` parameters and `visibility="gone"`. Then programmatically make layouts you need to be visible by using method `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `setVisibility(View.GONE)` to control which views are presently visible.

If I comprehended your problem correctly, this is what you need:

Define the same onClick method for all your topic buttons in **activity_main.xml**. Here I am using `displayTutorial`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="chapter1"
        android:id="@+id/chapter1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:onClick="displayTutorial"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="chapter2"
        android:id="@+id/chapter2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chapter1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="displayTutorial"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Define the `displayTutorial` method in **MainActivity** and build the new Activity start Intent with the extra information about which topic to display.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declare this global String for use with Intent extra key
    public static final String TOPIC_NUMBER= "topic_number";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void displayTutorial(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, tutorialpage.class);
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.chapter1:
                intent.putExtra(TOPIC_NUMBER, 1);
                break;
            case R.id.chapter2:
                intent.putExtra(TOPIC_NUMBER, 2);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    ...

}
```

Declare all tutorial layouts nested into one single layout

**activity_tutorialpage.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation"vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tutView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
            <!--Declare your layout for Topic 1-->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tutView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
            <!--Declare your layout for Topic 2-->
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout >
```

Finally in **tutorialpage.java** , capture the intent, fetch the data about topic number and selectively display that tutorial view.

```
public class tutorialpage extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorialpage);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int topicNumber = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.TOPIC_NUMBER,0);
        switch(topicNumber ) {
            case 1:
                RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tutView1);
                layout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
                break;
            case 2:
                RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tutView2);
                layout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
                break;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The error you got was because `getIntExtra` has the following signature:

> public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)

So you put any integer for the `defaultValue` because you are always going to put the topic number value along with the intent, so `defaultValue` will never be used.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I have made separate views on the tutorial xml page each with their own id and set them to invisible, but how would I call them to be in the onclick method inside the chapter java file because I have found findViewById but not an equivalent to call the other layouts from.

Comment: I've added my code and updated the question if it helps to understand my problem.

Comment: @GChanna I've posted an almost completely coded example, try and implement it.

Comment: Thank you, I have read through your code and tried to implement it but I still recieve an error. I understand the logic in your solution, the error btw is the line         int topicNumber = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.TOPIC_NUMBER);  just above the switch statement in tutorialpage.java  and that is producing an error as it expects a (string, int) but the error goes away if I hardcode a value such as (TOPIC_NUMBER, 1) or (TOPIC_NUMBER, 2) so I need some way of passing the value from the other switch statement.

Comment: It does achieve what I want to do if I put in (TOPIC_NUMBER, 1) or (TOPIC_NUMBER, 2), I am researching myself about it but do you know how to dynamically pass the number through. I tried some run throughs using CharAt and indexOf but it just produces a blank screen where if I hardcode (TOPIC_NUMBER, 1) or (TOPIC_NUMBER, 2) they present the first or second screen.

Comment: Sorry about that, its a minor mistake, I've edited and mentioned the cause and solution to this error.

Comment: It worked, that is weird because I tried 0 and it didn't work lol, thank you so much for your help, also before you answered I found another way of doing it which is:          Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        int topicNumber =  extras.getInt(MainActivity.TOPIC_NUMBER); if you know how that works how does this differ from your solution? I applied that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204869/can-not-getintextra-at-onactivityresult

Comment: There is a difference, there the data was extracted from a bundle which is extracted from the intent, and here we are extracting the int directly from the intent. So if you are to avoid using the defaultValue, replace the one line of int topicNumber = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.TOPIC_NUMBER,0) with these two lines Bundle data = intent.getExtras(); then int topicNumber = data.getInt(MainActivity.TOPIC_NUMBER);

Comment: Ok thank you, one last thing there is no major difference in performance or memory use between them is there, the only difference is how the data is extracted? I will stick with your way tbh as it is easier as it contains less lines and is thus less likely for me to call the wrong thing where I may need it or lose something I need in the future, once again your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Theoretically speaking the bundle object requirement does create a temporary extra memory usage but that is really insignificant. On the contrary, accessing it directly from the intent has the added advantage of defaultValue, like say you set defaultvalue for topic1 as 1, then if button for topic 1 was clicked you would not need to add the value since it'll be extracted from defaultValue.